# EPUB, combining all xml documents in a single xml file

Tags: xml, epub

Is it possible to combine all the xml documents in an EPUB in a single xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it relatively fast by using XSLT 2.0 :

See document() and collection() functions for reading the files.

Use the identify template for copying the content of each documents.

One of the advantage of using XSLT is that you are sure to obtain a well-formed XML.

I will try to post a sample soon.

Answer (score 0):

You might want yo look at *Sigil e-book editor* [link](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/). I know you can do it by hand, but may be there is a batch processing capabilities.

Comment: Thanks Nikiton but I want to do it programmatically in a server.